# How to solve arithmetic expressions with Flex/Bison

Tags: c, optimization, bison, lex

I'm working on a school project to optimize C code, the requirements, among others, are to solve arithmetic expressions in place and replace constants(#define).

In theory I think it may be easier to replace the constants first and then solve the arithmetic expressions. (in case some constants are arithmetic expressions)

But I can't write the code(and neither can my Compilers teacher) to a parser that recognizes the arithmetic expressions and solves them.

We're using Flex & Bison if anyone can give any pointers (no pun intended) to how to get this done would be great.

Comment: What part of the project do you find difficult? As written, this question is too broad to be answered with less than a book chapter.

Comment: @rici My difficulty lies in writing the bison program to solve the expressions after replacing the constants, I also don't know how to define them in the flex file in a way that I get all the possible ways of writing an arithmetic expression

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier if you providefsome concrete examples (input and desired output). But I don't understand why you think this is a *parsing* problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]My suggestion for solving arithmetic expressions is using stack with Dijkstra algorithm 
[Shunting-yard_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).
Or you can also use Binary Trees.[BinaryTree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/evaluation-of-expression-tree/)

Comment: Following your sugestion I've found this: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html
I believe I can work something out. Any other sugestions are still welcome

Comment: How does this apply if the user isn’t being very verbose with their use of parentheses? Should the compiler just add them based on operator precedence?

Comment: Actually befor using Dijkstra algorithm you have to convert it to parenthesized term

Comment: How does this relate to flex and bison? As far as I can see, you're just explaining how one might do it *without* flex and bison, which wasn't the question.

Comment: After reading more about this algorithm I've been able to write a little JS snippet to parse an arithmetic expression. And I've grasped the idea. When parethesis are not present the parser should process every OP in the stack with higher or equal precedence.
But the BIson and flex part are still a problem, I don't know how to write both files to parse C code for constants | expressions and replace | solve them